# Postman assertion for dates

Tags: rest, validation, datetime, postman, assertion

Getting the response for the dates in UTC format.

```
"date": "2021-05-30T00:01:03.699Z",
```

I've to validate it in Postman against the ui , which is in the local time, EST.
`Generated: 5/29/21, 8:01 PM`

how to do the assertions in Postman to validate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let moment = require("moment")
console.log(moment.utc().local().format("MM/DD/YY, HH:mm A"))
```

You can use moment.utc() to get current time and then use local to convert to local time

so in your case you can use moment.utc(time) to create utc from the response and the convert it to the format you want:

```
let moment = require("moment")
pm.expect(moment.utc("2021-05-30T00:01:03.699Z").local().format("MM/DD/YY, HH:mm A")).to.be.eql("05/30/21, 01:01 AM")
```

you can also use moment timezone using as mentioned in this collection:

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10825459/Szf3ZVCh?version=latest#585d7012-fddf-4e62-98be-7a1e3cc98693